# ¿Hay alguna alternativa oficial para escribir la ñ en teclados extranjeros?

Tags: ortografía, historia, letras

En el idioma alemán existen varias grafías, véase ä, ö, ü y ß, que pueden ser complicadas de escribir en algunos teclados. Sin embargo, ningún alemán se rasga las vestiduras si ve cualquiera de estos caracteres sustituido por sus versiones ASCII:

- ä >> ae
- ö >> oe
- ü >> ue
- ß >> ss

De este modo, cualquiera con un teclado que no sea alemán puede escribir en alemán y te entenderán perfectamente y sin ningún problema, siempre (por supuesto) que no sean documentos oficiales. Estas formas están incluso estandarizadas, aunque sea simplemente de facto.

Sin embargo, no creo que exista una versión "oficial" para sustituir la ñ [cuando es difícil escribirla](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12879/12637). He visto todo tipo de formas:

- La inglesa: n.
- La catalana: ny.
- La portuguesa: nh.
- La francesa: gn.
- La histórica: nn.

Obviamente, todos vamos a entender lo que se ha escrito de esta forma, al menos en la mayoría de los casos (*¡cono, un cono!*). Pero ¿se ha llegado alguna vez, en algún momento, a establecer una grafía alternativa de la ñ como oficial?

Comment: Un rápido vistazo a los resultados de la búsqueda "grafía alternativa eñe" da cuenta de qué poco consenso hay al respecto. Los foros españoles prefieren _nn_ y, especialmente, _ny_, pero seguro que en otros idiomas están de acuerdo en que debería ser otra.

Comment: @fedorqui y lo mal que suena "_Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die._" :)

Comment: Jaja ¡ya te digo! De hecho, [en la película](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JGp7Meg42U) no lo pronuncia demasiado bien : ) _Inniigo_.

Comment: Pienso que en esta época del desarrollo tecnológico no hay disculpa para escribirlo mal. Alternativa 1. Escribir la n y esperar que el corrector ortográfico lo corrija. Alternativa 2. Buscar en google cualquier palabra que tenga ñ y hacer un copiar y pegar. Alternativa 3. La usada en la antigüedad de presionar la tecla alt y escribir 164 en el teclado numérico. Alternativa 4. Configurar windows para que escriba en español así el teclado no tenga la letra ñ y usar la combinación de ~n o alt derecho + n.

Comment: @DGaleano tienes razón, opciones hay. También las hay para las grafías alemanas y eso no impide que haya grafías alternativas. Por otro lado, mi pregunta no se refiere solamente a la época actual, sino a cualquier época. Es lo que intentaba preguntar, si en algún momento se llegó a establecer una grafía alternativa oficial, históricamente hablando.

Comment: @DGaleano tu tercera alternativa no funciona en Mac. La cuarta tampoco. En Mac la forma de lidiar con esto es presionar la tecla opción junto con la N y luego nuevamente N.

Comment: @VladimirNu Excelente. O sea que en Mac también se puede hacer. Carlos, creo que la respuesta es "**En la actualidad** no hay disculpa para escribirlo mal sin importar el teclado o el sistema operativo."  Incluso para el [alemán](http://www.alemanista.com/como-escribir-caracteres-alemanes-teclado-aleman/) :-)

Comment: Para los pasaportes legibles a máquina (que solo permiten letras sin diacríticos), escríbese *NXX* por la *Ñ*). Esos según ICAO 9303 part 3 § 6 que también especifica *OE* por *Ö* pero no es precisamente para el uso de personas normales.

Comment: Twit de la RAE del 27/07/2016: "#RAEconsultas La RAE no ha propuesto ninguna escritura alternativa para la letra «ñ»."

Comment: En alemán las vocales con diéresis y la ligadura _essetz_ sirven para escribir con un solo signo lo que se escribía con dos y, por ocioso que parezca señalarlo, se inventaron después que los signos dobles que reemplazan. No deja de ser lo mismo que sucedió con la ñ, que reemplazó a la doble n, como señalas: la diferencia es que en español la ñ terminó siendo un sonido diferente, cosa que no pasó en el alemán.

Comment: @Yay Leí ese tuit ayer y me divirtió la cantidad de respuestas indignadas de personas que pensaban que se iba a suprimir la ñ. Como había leído antes esta pregunta, yo ya sabía cuál era el motivo real del tuit :)

Comment: En Argentina algunos sustituyen la ñ con ni, en vez de decir o escribir por ejemplo:
Coño, usan Conio.

Comment: If you have an QWERTY keyboard, you can use the International Keyboard. You have to load it in Windows and then you can type all the accents!! No es nada difícil teclear la eñe....

Comment: https://guides.mtholyoke.edu/c.php?g=101991&p=663129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya [se ha indicado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17523/hay-alguna-alternativa-oficial-para-escribir-la-%C3%B1-en-teclados-extranjeros#comment24134_17523), la RAE no ha lanzado una propuesta de grafía sustituta para transcribir el sonido nasal palatal /ɲ/ que representamos con la letra *ñ*. A lo largo de mi vida me ha tocado ver a personas que utilizan la secuencia ⟨ni⟩ para reemplazar a *ñ*, de modo que *año* se convierte en *anio*, por ejemplo.

Aunque los alemanes hayan «estandarizado» *de facto* una *e* pospuesta para las vocales con *umlaut*, con lo extendida que está la comunidad hispanoparlante dudo mucho que lleguemos a un acuerdo parecido para grafar un reemplazo de la eñe. Además, cualquier sustitución o aproximación de la eñe es ya innecesaria en la era del estándar Unicode: no hay excusa para no utilizar la [elegante y económica](http://polalaroids.blogspot.mx/2010/04/apologia-de-la-n.html) *ñ*.

Comment: aah, la dulce ironía de que el enlace http://polalaroids.blogspot.mx/2010/04/apologia-de-la-n.html está escrito con `n` :P

Comment: Y porqué lo haria ? Se puede utilizar el International Keyboard y se utilisa ALT + el signo de la ñ y después la  en. Sale perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente, cuando me toca sustituirla (normalmente al programar, que el compilador puede no reconocer ese símbolo) prefiero sustituirla por "ni", ya que al juntar esas dos letras con una vocal, se produce un sonido muy parecido al de la ñ + vocal.
Por ejemplo:

"ña", por "niá". "España" por "Espaniá". Además he observado que dicha sustitución ayuda a explicar el sonido "ñ" a los extranjeros que desean mejorar su pronunciación del castellano.

...y respondiendo a tu pregunta, siempre puedes escribir la "ñ" pulsando a la vez las teclas "altgr" y "4", y luego pulsando la tecla "n".

Answer (score 0):

Para quienes desistan de escribir la ñ, no digo nada, pero me parece importante señalar que siempre hay formas de teclear cualquier carácter.

[Aquí](https://filipiknow.net/enye/) se explican unos cuantos métodos para Windows. Me gusta especialmente el método B.b: tras la configuración necesaria basta con usar Alt-n para ñ y Alt-Shift-n para Ñ.

No he buscado procedimientos equivalentes para Linux o Mac (y eso que uso Linux), pero baste como ejemplo, porque imagino que la mayoría todavía usa Windows.